# how to add custom properties in drupal8's configuration entity

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I want to add custom properties in the configuration entity(user_role).

```
e.g. 
administrator {
    id: administrator,
    label: administrator,
    isadmin: true,
    ..,
--> client_id:1
}
```

but I couldn't find how to override to existing configuration entity's properties.

so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In general entities in Drupal 8 have `fields` (properties) that can be attached to them and can extend their functionality.

`Roles` are not real entities in Drupal 7 or 8 and they are not fieldable by default.  In Drupal 7 there is a [user_role_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_role_field) module which allows for this functionality but no equivalent in Drupal 8 exists at the moment.

**As an alternative** in Drupal 8 you can create `fields` for the `user entity` (included in core) and if you want `Role specific` fields you can assign [field_permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to each of the fields so specific roles can create/view/edit them.

Comment: This is incorrect. Roles are ConfigEntities, which are "real entities" even though they do not implement a fieldable interface.

They can be extended and altered in various ways. One example is by using third party settings: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/how-to-alter-or-add-additional-data-to-the-configuration-entities